# My "Time" class is stuck with the default data I set for hours, minutes and seconds, can't change their values by any means

Tags: c#, class

My homework assignment asks me to make a class called "Time". When I initialize two instances of the class, where one assigns the hours, minutes, and seconds randomly, and where the other one gets it's input from the parameters, it seems like both instances are stuck at the default "0:0:0".

This is the class:

```
class Time
    {
        private static int hours = 0;
        private static int minutes = 0;
        private static int seconds = 0;

        public static int Hours
        {
            get { return hours; }
            set { hours = (Hours > -1 && Hours < 24) ? Hours : 0; }
        }
        
        public static int Minutes
        {
            get { return minutes; }
            set { minutes = (Minutes > -1 && Minutes < 24) ? Minutes : 0; }
        }
        
        public static int Seconds
        {
            get { return seconds; }
            set { seconds = (Seconds > -1 && Seconds < 24) ? Seconds : 0; }
        }

        public Time() 
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            Hours = rand.Next(-1, 24);
            Minutes = rand.Next(-1, 60);
            Seconds = rand.Next(-1, 60);
        }

        public Time(int hour, int minute, int second) 
        {
            Hours = hour; 
            Minutes = minute;
            Seconds = second; 
        }

        public string Show() 
        {
            return $"{hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}";
        }
    }
```

This is the code in the Main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var T1 = new Time();
    var T2 = new Time(12, 24, 48);
    Console.WriteLine(T1.Show());
    Console.WriteLine(T2.Show());
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I've tried everything but nothing worked, maybe only I don't see the problem.

Comment: It seems unlikely you'd want to declare your private members static

Comment: Remove the `static` from your fields and properties

Comment: `rand.Next(-1, 24);` is wrong too, `Ramdon.Next` parameters are: first including and second excluding. So you include -1 as hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yea but they get bumped up to 0, so it statictically prefers 0:00:00 but doesn't wreck anything

Comment: What is `perc` in the Minutes property `set { perc = (...` ?

Comment: @CaiusJard Oh, excuse me, I was translating the variable names from hungarian and I left that out, perc is minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several problems:

1. Don't use `static` here. Static means same for every instance
2. Don't initialize your random hours, minutes and seconds with `rand.Next(-1, 24)` but `rand.Next(0, 24)`
3. The setters are wrong:

   ```
   set { hours = (Hours > -1 && Hours < 24) ? Hours : 0; }
   ```

You have to use `value` instead of `Hours`(same with other properties).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have solved something because now T2 works fine, I have removed the static keywords from hours, minutes, and seconds but then the next problem is present, one part of the assignment asks me to determine if it's before or after noon, then, I can't use hours, nor Hours because neither is a static

Comment: `if(T2.Hours < 12)` it's morning for t2

Comment: @CaiusJard Although this does work, the assignment requires that I calculate this in the class, we were given a UML diagram to work with. I learned many things from the answers so thanks for that as well. Now I know what the static keyword actually does so that's a big help.

Comment: Yeah, nothing in your class should be static.. And once you've made it that way you can do a property like `public bool IsMorning => (Hours < 12);`

Answer (score 0):

Static means that every new Time will have the same data, and changing it for one instance of Time changes it for all. Remove static from your field and property references, and it should work.